# Error: incompatible types: Message cannot be converted to int?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to make a `splashscreen` for an `Android app`, and I've used [this](http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html) tutorial. Everything is supposed to be fine, apart from the fact that `Android Studio` is giving me an error message saying that

> Message can't be converted to int.

I am assigning an `int` value to msg.what, but that is supposed to work, so I'm not really sure why it's giving me this error.
My code is below:

```
    private static final long SplashTime = 3000;
    private static final int StopSplash = 0;

    private ImageView splash;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == StopSplash) {
                splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashsheet);
        splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = StopSplash;

        splashHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg, SplashTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add Message class Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `sendEmptyMessageDelayed`, you should pass only `what` code as the first parameter:

```
splashHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(StopSplash, SplashTime);
```

On the other hand, you can use `sendMessageDelayed`:

```
splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SplashTime);
```